# Basic 2D plotting in javascript?

Tags: javascript, plot, google-chrome-app

I'm getting a stream of data via a [chrome app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/hid) and want a basic API to plot it.  Literally the simplest thing for a beginner is ideal (new to javascript).  Looking for basic help picking the right tools before I invest too much time into learning them.

I've recently discovered [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) and [simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/).

Comment: d3.js is nice, but it's not really a "basic" API.

Comment: d3 is not a plotting library, it's simply a DOM manipulation/creation library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://www.flotcharts.org/
I used it when I was a beginner with javascript, and it is pretty easy to start off with. You can take it way too many steps further, but end of the day all you need is simple arrays with x and y values

Comment: @Derek: d3.js can be a bit much to digest if youre a beginner (at least thats what I think)